# Creating a template class of a container

Tags: c++, templates

Im trying to create a class as container-wrapper, something like this

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename U>
class Test {
    T<U> list;
};

int main() {
  Test<std::vector, int> test;
}
```

But this wont work. I know it will work when I use it like this

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Test {
    T list;
};

int main() {
  Test<std::vector<int>> test;
}
```

but how would I write my insert?

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
    T list;

public:
    void insert(??? element) {
        ...
    }
};
```

TIA, Narase

Answer (score 3):

> But this wont work.

With your first snippet of `Test`, since `std::vector` has [two template parameters, `value_type` and `allocator_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), we must specify the existence of these template parameters in the declaration of `T` using *template template parameters* as follows.
Here I use variadic one and then `T<U...>` becomes legal for 
`T = std::vector` and compilation errors are removed.

> how would I write my insert?

The following code also shows an implementation example of `Test::insert`.
Since [this method can accept both lvalue and rvalue references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) in C++11 and over, here I apply the *forwarding reference* (which is what Scott Meyers calls [*universal reference*](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers),) to it.
In this approach, we does not need to specify the value type of `Test::list` in the `Test::insert` definition and passing wrong types to `Test::insert` causes compilation errors.
If you need the value type of `std::vector`, the member type `std::vector::value_type` is available:

```
template <template<class...> class T, class ...U>
class Test
{
    T<U...> list;

public:
    template<class ...V>
    void insert(V&& ...element) {
        list.insert(std::forward<V>(element)...);
    }

    typename T<U...>::iterator begin() noexcept {
        return list.begin();
    }

    typename T<U...>::iterator end() noexcept {
        return list.end();
    }

    using value_type = typename T<U...>::value_type;
};
```

This is an usage example with `std::vector`:

[**DEMO (std::vector)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GeeYh3ukxxFhXm9d)

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same<Test<std::vector, int>::value_type, int>::value, "oops!"); // OK.

Test<std::vector, int> test; // OK

test.insert(test.end(), 11);
test.insert(test.end(), 99);

for(auto it = test.begin(); it != test.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

As another example, this wrapper class also works with `std::map` as follows:

[**DEMO (std::map)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JG8VqFILndxZLIlr)

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same<Test<std::map, int, int>::value_type, std::pair<const int, int>>::value, "oops!"); // OK.

Test<std::map, int, int> test; // OK

test.insert(std::make_pair(1, 11));
test.insert(std::make_pair(2, 99));

for(auto it = test.begin(); it!= test.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

---

Finally, this is a fixed version of your second snippet:

[**DEMO (std::vector)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/l3ByxrN1FdfIV0Db)

[**DEMO (std::set)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r1sboquSyVB7fpV0)

```
template <class T>
class Test
{
    T list;

public:
    template<class ...V>
    void insert(V&& ...element) {
        list.insert(std::forward<V>(element)...);
    }

    typename T::iterator begin() noexcept {
        return list.begin();
    }

    typename T::iterator end() noexcept {
        return list.end();
    }

    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest one would be

```
template <typename T>
class Test {
    ....
    void insert(const typename T::value_type& element);
```

And/or, for completeness and move semantics compliance:

```
void insert(typename T::value_type&& element);
```